# disabling arrow keys in javascript while using onKeyUp

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

i searched for this but i was not able to find a question..maybe i did not used appropriate keyword..if it is duplicate i am sorry

Here is my question.I had written a code in `HTML`, `PHP`, `AJAX` and `Javascript`..I am checking for `online username availability` in the database after each character is entered.The problem is that `onKeyUp` is detecting `arrow` keys also as input

> left and right arrow keys

So when i try to insert a character in between the text entered in the textfield the `cursor` automatically moves to the end of the textfield..so modification in between the text is not possible.

Here is my `HTML code`

```
<input type = "text" name = "txt_username" id = "user" onKeyUp = "check_username(this.value)">
<span id = "check" style = 'color: green; font-size: 20px'> </span> <br>
```

and here is the `check_username()` function

```
function check_username(str) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var arr = xmlhttp.responseText.split("^");
            document.getElementById("user").value = arr[1];

            if (arr[0] == 2) {
                $("#check").html("Enter a username of at least 4 characters");
            } else if (arr[0] == 1) {
                $("#check").html("Username already exists");
            } else {
                $("#check").html("Username available");
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "username_check.php?txt_username=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

and here is my **username_check.php**

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("company");

$username = ($_REQUEST['txt_username']);
$a = 0;

if (strlen($username) < 4) {
    $a = 2;
    echo $a . "^" . $username;
} else if (checkexistence($username)) {
    $a = 1;
    echo $a . "^" . $username;
} else {
    $a = 0;
    echo $a . "^" . $username;
}

function checkexistence($username) {
    $check = mysql_query("select username from employee");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($check)) {
        if (strcmp($username, $row['username']) == 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
?>
```

How can I somehow manage(*by disabling or keeping some check*) the `arrow keys` so that text can be inserted in between??

Comment: As the below answer pointed out. You need to get the keyCode for those events and either call a function or `preventDefault`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is it:

```
<input type = "text" name = "txt_username" id = "user" onKeyUp = "if(!(event.keyCode>36&&event.keyCode<41)){check_username(this.value)}">
```

Comment: that was a fast one..i will accept it in `5 minutes`..now,i think i wasted too much time in writing question

Comment: i think this will be more appropriate condition `if(!(event.keyCode>36 && event.keyCode<41) && !(event.keyCode == 8))` we have to include `backspace` also..although your answer is correct according to the asked question

Comment: You should neither include `event.keyCode == 8` for backspace nor `event.keyCode == 46` for delete, because in those cases you will want to make a new search since the text has changed

Answer (score 2):

I'd make a slight adjustment in the `onkeyup` (HTML is case insensitive), use the element and the event, so you can use them in your callback:

```
<!-- use element and event as parameters -->
<input type = "text" name = "txt_username" id = "user" onkeyup = "check_username(this, event)">
<span id = "check" style = 'color: green; font-size: 20px'> </span> <br>
```

The callback can then check the event for keyCodes and use the element to send data and do manipulation when necessary:

```
function check_username(element, event) {
    if (event.keyCode > 36 && event.keyCode < 41) {
        // when arrow keys were pressed, do nothing
        return false;
    }

    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var arr = xmlhttp.responseText.split("^");
            if (element.value != arr[1]) {
                // only make change when required
                element.value = arr[1];
            }

            if (arr[0] == 2) {
                $("#check").html("Enter a username of at least 4 characters");
            } else if (arr[0] == 1) {
                $("#check").html("Username already exists");
            } else {
                $("#check").html("Username available");
            }
        }
    }
    // encode user name to use as get parameter
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "username_check.php?txt_username=" + encodeURIComponent(element.value), true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this script

```
$(document).keyup(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode >= 37 && e.keyCode <= 40) { 
       //do something
       return false;
    }
});
```

code 37 is left arrow
code 38 is up arrow
code 39 is right arrow
code 40 is down arrow

this script intercept keyup event in your document and manage arrows keys

try this more complete example

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
     $('#user').keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode >= 37 && e.keyCode <= 40) { 
           //do something e.g. e.preventDefault();
           return false;
        }
     });
})
```

Comment: can you tell where we have to include this script??

Comment: include it in your document ready.. I suggest to use keydown event and not keyup

Comment: what will be the advantage of using `onkeydown`??

Comment: I don't have a valid explanation for this, many times I had problems with that event. Use keyup, is better.. if you have some problem try change it in keydown